# Publish office VSTO addin into office store

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

Is that possible to publish an office add in (created for desktop outlook using vsto and I guess it works only on windows) in office store?
How to generate an xml manifest for it?

PS addin just customizes UI and doesn't need any web resources

Or probably there is a simple way to migrate to outlook App? without hosting any code on my server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, VSTO have to be deployed via an EXE installation package. Only apps for office (also call "office add-ins")  can be published into the office store. 
Apps for office contains a  Manifest + webpage,  VSTO contains only dlls.

To run a Apps for office, user needs to have Internet, conversely VSTO add-ins is fully functional without internet connection.

To know more about VSTO see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268878.aspx)

To know more about App for office see [here](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins)

Comment: Thanks! I've just found this topic https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c1b6d07-f172-4404-b6e1-028a8ba255f7/can-i-publish-an-excel-addin-to-the-office-app-store?forum=officestore